# Loading content of file in web app

Tags: web-services, file, azure, resources

I added few files (Build action `Content`, `Copy if newer`) to my project. It works, I can see these files in /bin directory where all others files are.

How can I access this files? I believe if this were console app or sth like that it would be easy (access by `LoadFile({path in bin dir})`), but it doesn't work on my WebApp hosted on IIS 7.5 or at Azure.

How could it be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on the .net language you're using you should be able to handle them using the [System.Io.File](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/system.io.file.aspx) static class.

So for instance, if you want to get the files that are in a folder within your webservice you can do something like

```
var folder = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/YourFolder")
string fullPath = Path.Combine(folder , "yourfile.txt");
var stream System.Io.File.OpenRead(fullPath);
```

EDIT: 
To access the resource folder created within the bin use :

```
var folderPath = Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "YourFolder");
```

Comment: `HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~");` provides path to app root, but not to bin dir. I don't think, manually adding bin is a good idea.

Comment: `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory` also points to web root directory. I tried this already.

Comment: have a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1199372/getting-the-current-directory-in-an-assembly-used-by-a-web-service-app-and-windo

Comment: bin is a terrible location for all kinds of security reasons.  Put the files in ~/App_Data then useServer.MapPath as Giorgio answered.