# Online path is not correct

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services

I have a web application and I need to update data in XML file named as "Setting.xml".
 I try this code for get the path:

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "Setting.xml");
```

I use the web service.
This code is work locally good, but after uploading to the server it doesn't work fine.
Could you help me, where is the error?

Comment: did you try to print out AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory on screen or into a logfile ?  (could be that that points to a in your case wrong directory)

Comment: I would refer you to this answer: 
http://stackoverflow.com/a/1199426/1432385

Comment: Have a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/674857/should-i-use-appdomain-currentdomain-basedirectory-or-system-environment-current)

Answer (score 0):

On the **Server**, check whether the Path `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "Setting.xml"` is valid and the file exists.